# How to override a HTML style id element with a class?

Tags: html, class

Follow the example below. A HTML page is generated with styles included (in WordPress). At some location, ID references are used: id-1, id-2, ....

Can I override all of the id-xxx with one class element?
I don't know how many id-xxx elements there are...
This sample below shows a yellow box. This need to be grey.

```html
    <html>

    <head>
      <style>
        .groupA {
          background-color: black;
          padding: 20px;
        }
        .groupB {
          background-color: gray;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        .groupC {
          background-color: white;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        #id-1 {
          background-color: yellow;
          margin: 30px;
        }
        #id-2 {
          background-color: yellow;
          margin: 30px;
        }
        #id-299 {
          background-color: yellow;
          margin: 30px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="groupA">
        <div class="groupB" id="id-1">
          <div class="groupC">
            Make the yellow box: grey - do not touch the id-xxx
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="groupA">
        <div class="groupB" id="id-2">
          <div class="groupC">
            Make the yellow box: grey - do not touch the id-xxx
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="groupA">
        <div class="groupB" id="id-299">
          <div class="groupC">
            Make the yellow box: grey - do not touch the id-xxx
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use !important;

e.g.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
   .groupA {
      background-color: black !important;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    .groupB {
      background-color: gray !important;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .groupC {
      background-color: white !important;
      padding: 5px !important;
    }
    #id-1 {
      background-color: yellow;
      margin: 30px;
    }
    #id-2 {
      background-color: yellow;
      margin: 30px;
    }
    #id-299 {
      background-color: yellow;
      margin: 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="groupA">
    <div class="groupB" id="id-1">
      <div class="groupC">
        This is my text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="groupA">
    <div class="groupB" id="id-2">
      <div class="groupC">
        This is my text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="groupA">
    <div class="groupB" id="id-299">
      <div class="groupC">
        This is my text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```